# select all <table> tags that has <input> and <section> tags in them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How can i select all `<table>` tags that has `<input>` and `<section>` tag in them
-by jQuery?

something like:

```
var tables_with_input = $( "table" that_contain input,section)  ///pseudo code
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? How would finding `<table>` that has these tags in it be of much use?

Comment: i made chrome extension and i try to find all tables in the page that contains this things for manipulate it after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) for that, it checks if the matching elements contains certain elements etc.

```
$('table:has(input, section)')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0572fno8/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var tables_with_input = $(context).find('table').has('input');
```

Comment: thank you on your the interesting answer! but @adeneo give it first :)